# Typo3: Edit the E-Mail template used by the form plugin

Tags: forms, typo3, typo3-extensions

currently I'm working on a contact form with the basic form plugin in Typo3. I got it all set up and it works fine and as expected. The only problem I have is that the email I receive looks quite bad. My form has 10 different inputs and it just return the field in some sort of list.

the output looks like this:

```
male
Test     
123  
test@test,de
1
```

While it should look something like this:

```
Gender: male
Name: Test   
Age: 123     
E-Mail: test@test,de
Agreed to TOS: yes
```

I've tried to google for a solution to this issue since I figured it can't be that hard to create a template for this but up to this point I haven't found anything that worked for me.

I've tried [this](https://www.sebkln.de/en/tutorials/detail/different-e-mail-templates-for-emailtosender-and-emailtoreceiver-finishers-in-ext-form/) solution right here and read through the github example provided but I don't know how to apply the solution to my project. I've implemented this code to my `.yaml` file:

```
templateName: 'template.html'
  templateRootPath:
    20: 'EXT:extension/Resources/Private/Forms/Templates/'
```

But as soon as I try to submit the form I get a bunch of errors. I also don't know what to write in the template file itself, I've tried to just copy [what's provided in the github](https://github.com/sebkln/form_examples/blob/master/Resources/Private/Forms/BasicContactFormExample/Frontend/Templates/Form.html) but somehow my code won't even find my template file.

Does anyone know a solution to this problem?

Comment: Which errors do you get? As indentation is important in YAML– are `templateName:` and `templateRootPaths:` equally indented? Please also check for proper option names (`templateRootPaths` must be plural)! Do you already use the file ending `.form.yaml` as described here? https://typo3.org/security/advisory/typo3-core-sa-2018-003/

Comment: Sorry for the late response, didn't have time to get to my PC today. The actual issue I described above was quite simple to fix and entirely my fault :D I just had to set Labels in my Backend for every input and I got the result I wanted. Even though its not pretty it will work for now.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that you're right about my issue with the template file @sebkln. Unfortunatly I can't test it right now but I will in my next project. FYI: The `templateName:` and `templateRootPaths:` are **not** equally indented. Could this be the reason it hasen't worked yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In YAML, indentation is used to indicate nesting (the structure of your configuration). Therefore, you'll need to make sure every setting is indented right.

`templateName` and `templateRootPaths` are both equal options of the email finisher in EXT:form:

```
finishers:
  -
    identifier: EmailToSender
    options:
      subject: 'Your message'
      recipientAddress: '{email}'
      recipientName: '{lastname}'
      senderAddress: your.company@example.com
      senderName: 'Your Company name'
      replyToAddress: ''
      carbonCopyAddress: ''
      blindCarbonCopyAddress: ''
      format: html
      attachUploads: true
      # The following part enables us to use the customized template:
      templateName: '{@format}.html'
      templateRootPaths:
        20: 'EXT:form_examples/Resources/Private/Forms/CustomHtmlMailExample/Sender/'
```

---

As you already figured out yourself, form labels will be rendered in the default email template of TYPO3's Form framework. Labels and form values will be rendered in a simple HTML table, if labels were set in the form definition.

Comment: Be advised that templateRootPaths, is the fullPath to and including the folder in which the MailTemplate is placed.